# Get name and value of system settings on Android

Tags: android, settings

I'm trying to create a macro for my device (Android 9) that sets a system setting to a specific value when I do an action. The problem is that I have no experience in coding for Android (and in general) and I don't know how the setting key is called or how to get that name.

The one I'm interested is "Bluetooth Audio LDAC Codec" in the developer options and its values.

Does anyone know the name or how can I get that?

This is for a S9+ using Macrodroid